# Install4j Windows 10 Apps & Feature Modify Button

Tags: install4j

When I successfully install a program with Install4j, the Uninstall button is enabled but the Modify button is disabled when I navigate to the Win 10 Apps & Features screen.  Is there a way to modify the installation components after the initial install on Windows 10 using this button?

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 7.0, this is not supported. I've added it to our issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I received a message from ej-technologies support.

I needed to check "Try to obtain full privileges if normal user" and enter the admin credentials when I'm uninstalling.

I'm told this is a Windows 10 bug (non-admin users should be able to clear out non-admin installed apps).  However, for my needs I only needed to make sure that the app could be cleanly uninstalled.